# Transferring a downloaded film from Nexus 7 to Nexus 10

Tags: google-play-movies

I recently downloaded Gravity, which I stupidly did on my Nexus 7, so I can't now watch it on TV, which I could have via HDMI if I'd downloaded it on my Nexus 10. I don't want to download it again (have only 20GB allowance per month). I've found the file and transferred it to my Nexus 10 but Google Play Movies acts like it's not there and wants to stream it or download again. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded it via Google Play Movies, correct?

The file is encrypted with DRM locked to a combination of your account AND the device used to download it. No way you're going to get that to play on anything else. You'll definitely need to redownload it it to watch it on the 10.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response which would explain why I'm having such a problem. Thought I was OK because Google's own information seemed to be saying you could log in on any device, so I assumed if it was on that device it would be accessible. https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1283330?hl=en "Watch movies & shows using a different account

You can watch a movie or TV show on any device that has the Google Play Movies & TV app. To watch, just sign in to the Google Account that you used to order the movie or TV show.

You can't transfer movies or TV shows between accounts."

Comment: You can watch the movie from a different device, but you still have to re-download it.  It's just stating that if you buy it or rent it on your google account, it will be accessible on any device that is associated with that google account.  You still have to download it on every device.

Comment: New-To-IT is correct. You CAN watch it on any device that your account that owns it is logged into. But you'll still be streaming or downloading it on each one individually. The DRM is tightly controlled.